# Чому "Märchendrama" — це "драма-феєрія"?

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова, from-german

Леся Українка [визначила жанр](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Forest_Song#/media/File:%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F._%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_1914_%D1%80.jpg) «Лісової пісні» як «Драма-феерія у 3-х діях». Але як видно з [її листа](https://uk.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F#CITEREF.D0.97.D1.96.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.96.D0.B2._.D0.A2.D0.BE.D0.BC_121979), вона не дуже задоволена такою назвою жанру:

> А от досада, що ніяк не можна по-нашому перекласти «Märchendrama» — «драма-феєрія» те, та не те. Як би його сказати? «Драма-казка» чогось незграбно, правда?

Отже, не дивлячись на те, що *[драма-феєрія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%94%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)* походить від французського *féerie*, собі на умі авторка мала саме *Märchendrama*.

Тоді що ж не так з перекладом *драма-казка*?

Оксана Забужко в «Notre Dame d'Ukraine» пише:

> <...> тут філологічна інтуіція Лесі Українки, як завжди, безпомильна: німецьке «Märchendrama» справді стоїть ближче до «містерії», водночас прямо не витикаючи на неї пальцем.

То як все-таки коректніше перекласти це слово?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Цілком суб'єктивна думка та спекуляція.

Звідси https://www.britannica.com/art/Marchen

> folktale characterized by elements of magic or the supernatural, such as the endowment of a mortal character with magical powers or special knowledge; variations expose the hero to supernatural beings or objects.

Звідси роблю висновок, що слово *Märchen*, хоч і перекладається як *казка*, має відтінок містичності, магії та загадковості (містерії). В українських казках теж зустрічаються магічні істоти та ситуації, але вони, як правило, мають більш соціально-повчальний характер (основний мотив популяризованих українських казок, як на мене, це - бідняк обдурив/покарав багача/пана). Коли в казках зустрічаються магічні істоти, вони зазвичай мають другорядні функції, часто злих сил (баба яга, бабай і т.д.), але при цьому, як я вже написав вище, найчастіше казка вчить виходити із складних ситуацій за допомогою хитрості, розуму чи/та сили. Також українські казки дуже часто жартівливі і веселі. Я веду до того, що українські казки, як правило не такі "темні" як ті ж німецькі, де дуже часто відьма чи інші магічні істоти стають основою казки, і сама казка доволі похмура і страшна (маючи певний відтінок безвихідності).

Базуючись на такій гіпотезі, можна сказати, що той відтінок, який шукає Леся Українка, має бути темнішим, більш магічним, загадковим, тоді як при перекладі *драма-казка*, твір набуває радше весело-жартівливого відтінку.

Доповнення :

> То як все-таки коректніше перекласти це слово?

Як на мене,на жаль, немає точного перекладу. Він сильно залежить від твору, і в цьому конкретному випадку я би переклав як *містична драма* або *містична казкова драма*. Можливо, *трагічна казка*.